# In ruby when I try mytext.include? (">Model number<") is returning false

Tags: ruby, string, watir

In ruby when I try `mytext.include?(">Model number<")` is returning `false`.
But `mytext.include?("Model number")` is returning `true`
What is wrong in the first condition?

`mytext` contains the string `"Model number"` inside `">"` and `"<"`

This is relevant HTML:

```
<div class="bucket"> <div class="h1"><strong>Product Specifications</strong></div> <div class="content"> <div class="tsSectionHeader">Product Information</div> <div class="tsTable"> <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Model number</span><span>516C</span></div> <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Maximum weight recommendation</span><span>35 Pounds</span></div> <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Material Type</span><span>Wood</span></div> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: 1.9.2p290 :001 > ">Model number<".include?(">Model number<")
 => true 
I suspect your string mytext is not what you think it is.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure `mytext` contains the exact string *>Model number<* somewhere, including capitalization?

Comment: mytext is a page source not a static string. but it has >Model number< when I see the page source.

Comment: ">Model number<".include?(">Model number<") when I try like this it returns true. but when i call the browser.text.include?(">Model number<") it return false

Comment: Have a look at `browser.text`, if it's HTML in there, the `<` might actually be a `&lt;`, the `>` a `&gt;`.

Comment: Yes I am sure they are > & <, and there is space in between

Comment: Can you post, verbatim, the bit of page source you're expecting to match?

Comment: @Chowlett <div class="bucket">
  <div class="h1"><strong>Product Specifications</strong></div>
    <div class="content">
     <div class="tsSectionHeader">Product Information</div>
     <div class="tsTable">
       <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Model number</span><span>516C</span></div>
       <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Maximum weight recommendation</span><span>35 Pounds</span></div>
       <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Material Type</span><span>Wood</span></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>

Comment: `'<div class="bucket"> <div class="h1"><strong>Product Specifications</strong></div> <div class="content"> <div class="tsSectionHeader">Product Information</div> <div class="tsTable"> <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Model number</span><span>516C</span></div> <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Maximum weight recommendation</span><span>35 Pounds</span></div> <div class="tsRow"><span class="tsLabel">Material Type</span><span>Wood</span></div> </div> </div> </div>'.include? ">Model number<" # => true`

Comment: What is mytext? Is it browser.text or browser.html? If it is the former, then mytext will not include the < > since they are only part of the HTML (not text).

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn some HTML. `>` and `<` are part of `span` tag: `<span></span>`.

This is where the text appears:

```
<span class="tsLabel">Model number</span>
```

So a `span` has text `Model number`. You can get the text using Watir with this:

```
browser.span(:class => "tsLabel").text
```